# how to add whole host to git?

Tags: git

I want add all files that start with `syslog` on my host to git. That seems crazy, but I think it could manage some config snippet to git repository.

My `.gitignore` is:

```
$ cat /.gitignore
/*
!/**/sysgit*
```

But it can't pick up a file at `/Users/myusername/tmp/sysgit_test` with `git status`.

Does git support this?

Comment: Is `sysgit` a typo for `syslog`? If so, is it just a typo here or does it appear in your actual `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, according to [man gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any
>   patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are
>   defined.

`git status --untracked=all` is very close to solving your problem, but still doesn't show untracked files in subdirectories. This one looks like a bug actually.